# SQL : create column with default value 0.00

Tags: sql, postgresql, syntax

I am trying to create a new column called `credit`, whose default value should be `0.00`
I am in PSQL postgres so I tried doing:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD credit FLOAT(2) DEFAULT '0.00';
```

But the column just shows `0` and not `0.00`

I tried doing  `ADD credit FLOAT(10,2) DEFAULT '0.00';` 
but this does not compile

Comment: Don't store money in floating point variables. BTW: there is a `MONEY` data type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't worry about what the value *shows* as.  The value is being set correctly.

If you want two decimal points, though, you should use `decimal`/`numeric`:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
    ADD credit DECIMAL(10, 2) DEFAULT 0.00;
```

This should show as `0.00`.

Note that quotes are not needed around number constants.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=9dbec40191616b2f91c305802c20417e) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: what about the type numeric ? is it the same ?

Comment: @sqlll . . . No, it is generally better.  `Numeric`/`decimal` (which are synonyms) implement fixed-point decimal numbers rather than floating point.